# Stop div overlapping a container

Tags: html, css

Ok so I am currently building a bespoke WordPress theme and I'm just having one of those moments where my head is completely blank... It's like I know it but I just can't figure it out!

Basically I have a spotlight section where it has an image, and then a container at the bottom of that image which displays the title and a short description etc... See screenshot: http://prntscr.com/ksh0tf

Basically I've done the img with an  to style it (set height / width, object fit etc) and then I have done the container div that holds the content, as a position: absolute and put a bottom: 0 - (in this case bottom: 4px due to it being out of place a tiny bit) as I want it to be at the bottom of the image each time no matter the height of the box etc. On the black container I have a width: 100% set and as you can see, it's causing it to overlap right over to the other div. This is also built off bootstrap too so it's a col-sm-8 and col-sm-4 but it just seems the text container div doesn't wanna just fit across the length of the image etc.

Here is my HTML code:

```
    <?php if ($atts['spotlightcolour'] == 'black' ) : ?>
    <div class="spotlight-container">
        <img class="spotlight" src="<?php echo $atts['bgimage']['data']['icon']; ?>" />
        <div class="spotlight-box" style="background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);">
            <?php echo $atts['title']; ?>
            <br />
            <?php echo $atts['description']; ?>
        </div>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

CSS:

```
    img.spotlight{
    height: 256px;
    width: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
}

.spotlight-box{
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    bottom: 4px;
    z-index: 3;
    display: block;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 20px;
}
```

I just want the container div that has the content in, to sit across the length of the image when width: 100% is set due to these could all be different sizes so I don't want to give set widths etc.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: It really helps if you can present your code as a snippet demonstrating the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Since `.spotlight-box` is absolutely positioned, its parent needs to be relatively positioned if you want it to sit properly inside the parent:

```
.spotlight-container {
  position: relative;
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ctdu9bzk/4/

Comment: Thanks a lot! Knew it was something simple, just couldn't figure it out. Mind was blank! Thanks a lot :)